# How do you filter on not null values elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to filter out values with not null :

Exemple with sql

```
SELECT ALL FROM Mytable WHERE field_1 NOT NULL and field_2 ="alpha"
```

How should I be writing this query in elasticsearch-dsl(python)?

I tried things like:

```
s = Mytable.search().query(
Q('match', field_2 ='alpha')
).filter(~Q('missing', field='field_1'))
```

but it returns elements with null values of field_1

Also, I tried this down, but it didn't work

```
field_name_1 = 'field_2'
value_1 = "alpha"
field_name_2 = 'field_1'
value_2 = " "
filter = { 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
            "match": {
                field_name_1 : value_1
            }
            },
            {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                field_name_2: {
                                    "textContent": "*"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    } }
                ]
            }
            }
        ]
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with elasticsearch-dsl(python), but the following search query, will get you the same search result as you want :

```
SELECT ALL FROM Mytable WHERE field_1 NOT NULL and field_2 ="alpha"
```

**With the help of below search query, the search result will be such that `name="alpha"` AND `cost` field will `not be null`. You can refer [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to know more about this.**

**Index Data:**

```
 {  "name": "alpha","item": null }
 {  "name": "beta","item": null  }
 {  "name": "alpha","item": 1    }
 {  "name": "alpha","item": []   }
```

**Search query:**

You can combine a bool query with a exists query like this:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": "alpha"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "item"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my-index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 1.6931472,
    "_source": {
      "name": "alpha",
      "item": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @Xoshabi did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from u

Comment: thank you @Bhavya; I found that my database was empty so it didn't return anything .

Comment: @Xoshabi thank u for accepting the answer :) Can u pls upvote this also by clicking on the up arrow on the left side of answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
s = Mytable.search()
.query(Q('bool', must=[Q('match', field_2='alpha'), Q('exists', field='field_1')]))
```

This is the way to use [boolean compound query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
                    query: {
                      bool: {
                        must: [
                          {
                            bool: {
                              must_not: {
                                missing: {
                                  field: 'follower',
                                  existence: true,
                                  null_value: true,
                                },
                              },
                            },
                          },
                          {
                            nested: {
                              path: 'follower',
                              query: {
                                match: {
                                  'follower.id': req.currentUser?.id,
                                },
                              },
                            },
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    },
```