# Elastic search query to avoid empty values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want fetch only values which shouldn't  be empty in case of text,

Please help me how can I write search query, I tried by using
"must_not":""
But it's not working. Pls help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Elasticsearch curl query for not null and not empty("")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745210/create-elasticsearch-curl-query-for-not-null-and-not-empty) or maybe [How do you filter on not null values elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62966644/how-do-you-filter-on-not-null-values-elasticsearch)

Comment: Yes almost, thanks for sharing